# Why do I miss some iterations in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, spyder

I have a Parts of Speech (POS) tagged parallel corpus with 25 files in the source language in `directory1` and 25 files in the target language in `directory2`. Each file contains 1000 lines i.e. 25000 lines per directory.

**Task at hand:** I want to remove the POS tags and then write all the text in the source and target language in a single-single text file, say, `source.txt` & `target.txt`.

Fortunately, I did this (see code below) but when I run the code - sometimes `source.txt` or `target.txt` has 24896 lines or 24871 lines etc but not 25000. After running the code for 2-3 times I get 25000 lines for both files.

`Sample POS tagged input: Need\VBN of\IN delivery\NN with\IN operation\NN .\.`

This behavior is mysterious to me (non-CS grad). **Is there any explanation for this behavior or it is just like that.**

*Pardon me if it is a dumb question!*

```
outfile1 = open("source.txt",'w')
outfile2 = open("target.txt",'w')

path = '/somePath/'
file_names = []; tempDataSrc = []; tempDataTrg = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            file_names.append(os.path.join(root, file))

file_names = sorted(file_names)

for file in file_names:  
    if ("Src_" in file): # filtering source language files
        infile1 = open(file,'r')
        for line_s in infile1:
            line_s = " ".join(word.split("\\")[0] for word in line_s.split())
            tempDataSrc.append(line_e)

for file in file_names: 
    if ("Trg_" in file): # filtering target language files
        infile2 = open(file,'r')
        for line_t in infile2:
            line_t = " ".join(word.split("\\")[0] for word in line_t.split())
            tempDataTrg.append(line_p)

for line1 in tempDataSrc:
    outfile1.write(line1+'\n')

for line2 in tempDataTrg:
    outfile2.write(line2+'\n')
```

NOTE: I have conda installation with python 3.6.  I am running my code in Spyder IDE; OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5

*PS: Any suggestions for writing the code in more pythonic way are also encouraged*

Comment: `file_names = [], tempDataSrc = [], tempDataTrg = []` is not valid python.

Comment: @salparadise I did this here to make the code compact.

Comment: so please use ";"  which makes it valid.

Comment: Is this all the code? How are you running it? Have you tried running from the terminal?  Because this part of the code seens quite deterministic - the results you ar reporting could only happen in race conditions with the same open file been read in different threads or something.  Could  be the effect of trying to naively paralelize the above code.

Comment: after running 2-3 times and you get 25k lines per file. My question would be what are these lines? Are they they 25 1000 lines of source and target text you expected or are they possible repeat lines ? etc..

Comment: This is not reproducible. For one, you're populating `tempDataSrc` and `tempDataTrg`, but iterating the completely undefined `tempDataEng` and `tempDataPun`. Make code that *actually runs* and exhibits your problem (a [MCVE]). We're not here to debug your junk pseudocode.

Comment: @jsbueno Yes, this is exactly the code I'm running. It is indeed quite deterministic but still behaving oddly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I corrected it. Actually English is the source language, so Eng and Punjabi is the Target language so Pun. Sorry for that!

Comment: @ssokhey: Fixing the wrong names doesn't help if you don't actually run your code locally. Come back when you have run the *exact*  code posted, and it still has the problem.

Comment: @localplutonium I have got exactly the data I need (no repetitions) but not on the first run.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did run it locally. It is running fine.. I just changed some variable names to make it look more general.

Comment: @ssokhey: Yeah, that doesn't count. You know how I know? It still doesn't run, because your iteration variables (the line names) don't match. And I can't trust that anything else matches either. **Edit**: Still broken. You're knee jerk reacting to specific criticisms, and not even bothering to look for the errors yourself. I'm done here.

Comment: Try closing the files at the end of the code to make sure they are completely flushed to the disk: `outfile1.close(); `outfile2.close()`

Comment: @Craig This works! But why?

Comment: I agree with @ShadowRanger, if after getting all these feedbacks the code still doesn't run - I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the behavior has to do with your environment for running the program )either the IDE or your OS itself) being abruptly killing the process, and it is not finishing to write the output to the files - as you don't close our output files in the code.

You can fix that by simply calling the `.close()` method on "outfile1" and "outfile2" at the very end of your code.

But, as you asked for input on doing things in a more Pythonic way: since you only write to the output at the end of your script, it makes sense to only "open" then near that part of the code as well. And since we are at it, you might as well use th e `with` statement to create and write to both files - that will ensure all data produced is flushed to the disk saved even in the case of early termination due to other errors:

```
with open("source.txt",'w') as outfile1:
    for line1 in tempDataSrc:
        outfile1.write(line1+'\n')

with open("target.txt",'w') as outfile2:
    for line2 in tempDataTrg:
        outfile2.write(line2+'\n')
```

(The `with` statement will automatically close the files and flush the data).

Comment: That is exactly the solution and suggestion I was looking for. Thank you!